# Tidyverse asking me to install every package individually

Tags: r, tidyverse

I just upgraded to R 3.5.1 and upon issuing the command `library(tidyverse)` I keep getting R Studio asking me to install each `tidyverse` application individually.

```
library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 package ‘Rcpp’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
```

Once I installed (for example) `Rcpp` it the console then warns me I need to install `glue` `yaml` `tibble` `tidyselect` `purr` and every app under the sun.

If I `install.packages("tidyverse") it just says the same error shown above, "package ‘XYZ’ was installed by an R version with different ".

Where can I find the full list of packages to install so I can just issue one command `install.packages(c("yaml", "Rcpp", "glue", "tidyselect", etc etc)`?

Comment: `utils::install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')`?

Comment: @Andre Elrico That command did execute, but the console is still asking me to install each package individually. I get error `package or namespace load failed for ‘pacakge XYZ’:` upon trying to load the `tidyverse`